# Filter not reset when filtering in header for tabulator

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabulator

I have data with Active & Inactive records which I displays using tabulator ver 4.6 javascript library. My requirement is to show Active data initially on page load.

I created table using below code & added initialHeaderFilter & initialFilter to dispaly an active records which works perfectly. But when I clears filter for column relation_status it does not show all data meaning here it does not show inactive records.

```
  $('#example-table').tabulator({
    layout:"fitColumns",
    pagination:"local",       //paginate the data
    paginationSize:5, 
    initialHeaderFilter: [{field:'Relation_Status',  value:'Active'}] ,
    initialFilter:[      {field:"Relation_Status", type:"=", value:"Active"}],
    columns: [
          { field: "Relation_Type", title: 'Relation Type' , headerFilterParams:{values:true}, headerFilter:"select" , headerFilterParams:paramLookup },

          { field: "Relation_Status", title: 'Relation Status' ,editorParams:{values:{"Active":"Active", "Inactive":"Inactive"}}, 
                    editor:"select", headerFilterParams:{values:true},  headerFilter:"select" },
          { field: "Related_clientCompany", title: 'Related Company' },
          { field: "Job_Link", title: 'Action ' },
      ]
  } );


  $("#example-table").tabulator("setData", RelatedCompanies);
```

My table looks as below when it load initially & it shows filter value "Active" in header & displays filtered data correctly but clearing filter (Below in red mark there is cross button X to clear records) does not show All records (including inactive) & it only shows Active records. What setting I am missing here ?

[image]

Comment: Tabulator version?
How are you clearing the filters, as you have two filters?
Also there are only two choices Active/Inactive, not sure what you are using for both?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Thanks for your comments, I have modified my question, I am using 4.6 ver & there is X button in column header to clear records which I shown in red mark.

Answer (score 0):

I used below code which solved my issue which I used after setData().

```
table.setHeaderFilterValue("Relation_Status", "Active");
```

And I commented below code

```
//initialHeaderFilter: [{field:'Relation_Status',  value:'Active'}] ,
//initialFilter:[      {field:"Relation_Status", type:"=", value:"Active"}],
```